# Azure Automation Account Runbook error with AZ

Tags: azure, automation, azure-runbook

When attempting to setup a runbook to scale down the size of a App Service Plan, I get the following error. How can I overcome this error?

I know my PS is valid and works.

```
Set-AzAppServicePlan -Name 'plan-api-dev' -ResourceGroupName 'rg-dev' -Tier S1 -WorkerSize Small
```

--

```
System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Set-AzAppServicePlan' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery.LookupCommandInfo(String commandName, CommandTypes commandTypes, SearchResolutionOptions searchResolutionOptions, CommandOrigin commandOrigin, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery.LookupCommandProcessor(String commandName, CommandOrigin commandOrigin, Nullable`1 useLocalScope)
   at System.Management.Automation.ExecutionContext.CreateCommand(String command, Boolean dotSource)
   at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.AddCommand(PipelineProcessor pipe, CommandParameterInternal[] commandElements, CommandBaseAst commandBaseAst, CommandRedirection[] redirections, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Set-AzAppServicePlan cmdlet belongs to the Az.Websites module. Just as you import the modules into Powershell before you use them, you need to ensure that you have imported Az.Websites module into your Automation account. You can refer to [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#import-az-modules) documentation to see how to do that.